# BASH CURL - Save all posted data to log file?

Tags: bash, curl, logging

I'm using CURL to post some data to a web server, this is working well but I'd like to save the values I'm posting to a log file for reference.

The code I'm using is:

```
curl -k -u user:password -s \
    -d "site=TEST" \
    -d "Contact=Tom" \
    -d "Desc=Remote Location" \
    -d "ID=123" \
-XPOST  "https://192.168.0.1/sites/update.php" > /dev/null
```

Currently I'm echoing the key and value pair to a log file using:

```
echo "site=TEST" > $log
echo "Contact=Tom" >> $log
echo "Desc=Remote Location" >> $log
echo "ID=123" >> $log
```

Which doesn't seem very efficient.

I can add `--trace-ascii $log \` to my curl command and that will log everything but it includes much more than I need. I only want the key and value pairs submitted.

Is this possible ?

Thanks

**UPDTAED**
To show the echo commands using the append operator.

Comment: Hi Tom, you could use the #!/bin/bash -x directive in a script which will then output the parsed curl command, then you can use grep and sed (or some other text manipulation) to format the output before redirecting it to log file. Also in your original approach above, you probably want to use the append operator >> after you've created the log file.

Comment: @user1621986 thanks, I do you the append operator, that was a typo when creating this ticket. I'll update that.  Can you point me in the right direction on how to use -x and what it does. Thanks

Comment: It's like a trace facility for scripts and outputs each line it executes: so in your case you could have something like: #!/bin/bash -x
curl -k -u user:password -s \
    -d "site=TEST" \
    -d "Contact=Tom" \
    -d "Desc=Remote Location" \
    -d "ID=123" \
-XPOST  "https://192.168.0.1/sites/update.php". If you run the script it will output "+ curl + dummy.sh -k -u user:password -s -d site=TEST -d Contact=Tom -d 'Desc=Remote Location' -d ID=123 -XPOST https://192.168.0.1/sites/update.php", so I was thinking you could extract what you need from that and send to file

Comment: Thanks, the script has lots of commands in it most of which don't need logging. I'll try it and see if this helps.

Comment: Yep, you could use grep "curl -k" in the first instance to isolate your curl line. Another option might be to stick the curl command in its own script

Comment: Take a look at [how-can-i-print-only-certain-commands-from-a-bash-script-as-they-are-run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106776/how-can-i-print-only-certain-commands-from-a-bash-script-as-they-are-run)